# flash builder 4 and eclim

Tags: actionscript-3, flexbuilder, eclim

Is it possible to get these two working together?  When I try to install the eclim (1.6.0) installer complains about the eclipse version.

Answer (score 1):

Flash Builder 4 is based on Eclipse 3.5.

If you look at the news section of eclim webpage: http://eclim.org/, we can see that eclim 1.6 requires eclipse 3.6

Try downloading and installing eclim 1.5 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclim/files/, which was the version corresponding to eclipse 3.5 (as seen on the news section of eclim webpage)

matb